# Where do I store a logged in user data in my react app

Tags: node.js

Building a little project right now with React, Redux, + Node

I need some help understanding where to store user data.

I am building a react web app with OAuth user authentication. When a user gets verified, I pull some data down, store it into the redux store, and make a cookie.

When a user exits the page and revisits the page, it checks to see if the cookie exists. If it does, pull the data from the cookie and shove it back into the redux store.

Is this safe? If it isn't, how should I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: it's good yes.Nothing is truly secure anyways

Comment: You may want to use https requests